# Setting IP in Apache vhost as testing domain

Tags: linux, apache, ip, vhosts

I was wondering if I can set the server external IP as a domain for testing.

On my Amazon server setup it works because all the domains point to the same folder.

```
domain1.com - /var/www/domain1
domain2.com - /var/www/domain2
ex.ter.nal.ip - /var/www/
```

So I can use ex.ter.nal.ip/test for a testing website.

On my Linode setup I moved the folders inside the user directories

```
domain1.com - /home/user1/public/domain1
domain2.com - /home/user2/public/domain2
ex.ter.nal.ip goes to domain2.com (I think it points to the last enabled site in Apache -a2ensite)
```

Is there a way to make it work?
I tried adding a vhost with  with the /home/test DocumentRoot, but then all the websites point to the test directory.

My domain vhost file looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName  www.domain1.com
  ServerAlias domain1.com

  DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
  DocumentRoot /home/user1/public/domain1.com/public

  <Directory /home/user1/public/domain1.com/public>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My testing one looks lithe this, but when enabled all the domains point to the test folder

```
<VirtualHost ex.ter.nal.ip>
  ServerName ex.ter.nal.ip

  DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
  DocumentRoot /home/test/public

  <Directory /home/test/public>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Ensure that your ServerName is specified in the Vhost. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html

Comment: Thanks, it is specified. I added my vhost files content above, to make it more clear.